# How to distribute maximum chocolates among k students

Tags: java, algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview -

> **Maximum number of chocolates to be distributed equally among *k* students**
>    Given *n* boxes containing some chocolates arranged in a row. There are *k* number of students. The problem is to distribute maximum number of chocolates equally among *k* students by selecting a consecutive sequence of boxes from the given lot. Consider the boxes are arranged in a row with numbers from 1 to *n* from left to right. We have to select a group of boxes which are in consecutive order that could provide maximum number of chocolates equally to all the *k* students. An array **arr[]** is given representing the row arrangement of the boxes and **arr[*i*]** represents number of chocolates in that box at position *i*.
>
> Examples:
>
> > Input : arr[] = {2, 7, 6, 1, 4, 5}, k = 3
> >     Output : 6
> >     The subarray is **{7, 6, 1, 4}** with sum 18.
> >     Equal distribution of **18** chocolates among **3** students is **6**.
> >     Note that the selected boxes are in consecutive order with indexes **{1, 2, 3, 4}**.

I found the [solution in Geekforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-number-chocolates-distributed-equally-among-k-students/) --

```
static int maxNumOfChocolates(int arr[], int n, int k) 
{ 
    // Hash table 
    HashMap <Integer,Integer> um = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); 

    // 'sum[]' to store cumulative sum, where 
    // sum[i] = sum(arr[0]+..arr[i]) 
    int[] sum=new int[n]; 
    int curr_rem; 

    // To store sum of sub-array having maximum sum 
    int maxSum = 0; 

    // Building up 'sum[]' 
    sum[0] = arr[0]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + arr[i]; 

    // Traversing 'sum[]' 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

        // Finding current remainder 
        curr_rem = sum[i] % k; 

        // If true then sum(0..i) is divisible 
        // by k 
        if (curr_rem == 0) { 
            // update 'maxSum' 
            if (maxSum < sum[i]) 
                maxSum = sum[i]; 
        } 

        // If value 'curr_rem' not present in 'um' 
        // then store it in 'um' with index of its 
        // first occurrence 
        else if (!um.containsKey(curr_rem) ) 
            um.put(curr_rem , i); 

        else
            // If true, then update 'max' 
            if (maxSum < (sum[i] - sum[um.get(curr_rem)])) 
            maxSum = sum[i] - sum[um.get(curr_rem)]; 
    } 

    // Required maximum number of chocolates to be 
    // distributed equally among 'k' students 
    return (maxSum / k); 
}
```

This works but I needed some explanation WHY this works, i could understand the part --

```
 if (curr_rem == 0) { 
           // update 'maxSum' 
           if (maxSum < sum[i]) 
               maxSum = sum[i]; 
       }
```

Will work if consecutive sum of array elements are divisible by k, but trying to understand this part --

```
else if (!um.containsKey(curr_rem) ) 
        um.put(curr_rem , i); 

    else
        // If true, then update 'max' 
        if (maxSum < (sum[i] - sum[um.get(curr_rem)])) 
        maxSum = sum[i] - sum[um.get(curr_rem)];
```

Any explanation here would be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very short explanation:

In the main loop you look at all sums from index 0 to the current index. If you have a remainder you have to check if you can “make it go away” by starting from another index than 0.

Checking for that is exactly the same thing as finding an equal remainder stored before.

E. g. you had remainder 3 at index 7. If you have remainder 3 again at index 13 you have no remainder by adding between 7 and 13.
What remains is taking the max. sum of all solutions found.

Comment: You could add example like `S(7)=k*i1+Reminder`, `S(13)=k*i2+Reminder` where `i2 > i1`. So, `S(8..13)=S(13)-S(7)=(k*i2+Reminder)-(k*i1+Reminder)` and `S(8..13)=k*i2 + Reminder - k*i1 - Reminder=k*i2-k*i1=k*(i2-i1)`. And so So, S(8..13) is multiple by k.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solve
{
//arr -> chocolates values, n = len(arr), k->no of students
//Idea:
//1.to use prefix sum and find the subarray whose sum is divisible by k.
//2.when we find the subarray we try to find the sum of this subarray by using 
//precomputation sum of arr
//3.we keep a max variable to record the max sum and return max that's it!!!!!
    static int maxNumOfChocolates(int arr[], int n, int k) 
    { 
        if(n==0)return 0;
        int []prefix = new int[n];
        prefix[0] = arr[0];
        for(int i=1;i<n;++i){
            prefix[i] = prefix[i-1]+arr[i];
        }
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(0,-1);
        int ans = -1;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            sum+=arr[i];
            if(map.containsKey(sum%k)){
                int j = map.get(sum%k);
                ans = Math.max(ans,prefix[i]-((j>=0)?prefix[j]:0));
            }
            map.putIfAbsent(sum%k,i);
        }
        if(ans==-1)return -1;
        return ans/k;
    } 

}
```